# Does ExternalName service act as a reverse proxy?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I have the following need:
There is API that may be accessed only from allowlisted IPs. I'd like to make this API available publicly.
I thought about the following solution:

1. Create a service of type `ServiceName`:

```yaml
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: my-svc
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: restricted-api.com
```

2. Create an ingress:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - mysite.com
      secretName: mysite-tls
  rules:
    - host: example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /api(/|$)(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: my-svc
                port:
                  name: https
```

Is my understanding correct that with such a setup when I call `https://example.com/request` on K8s level the request will be sent to `https://restricted-api.com/request`? The caller would not know that there is communication with `restricted-api.com`. Since the clients' IPs are dynamic the `restricted-api.com` would not allow them to call it.
The k8s IP is static and I could allowlist it.

Comment: Could you please describe what is your actual result and expected one?

Comment: @Bazhikov I don't have results yet, I don't even have Kubernetes cluster set up yet, since I'm still investigating. My expectation is as follows: I have an API that has restricted access (IP allowlisting). My Kubernetest cluster would be whitelisted. I want to create an endpoint on my k8s that will open the restricted API publicly (or at least to those who have access to that K8s endpoint). So, k8s ingress would act as a reverse proxy, and the restricted API would be an actual backend. Users should only communicate with K8s endpoint, they shouldn't communicate with restricted API directly.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if these are just your thoughts, I would recommend to look into this annotation:

> `externalTrafficPolicy=local` is an annotation on the Kubernetes service resource that can be set to preserve the client source IP. When this value is set, the actual IP address of a client (e.g., a browser or mobile application) is propagated to the Kubernetes service instead of the IP address of the node.

For more information you can find [here](https://blog.getambassador.io/externaltrafficpolicy-local-on-kubernetes-e66e498212f9) or in [official Kubernetes docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#external-traffic-policy).

Feel free to reach me out again, if you start to realize your thoughts and will face any issue with this.